# Group by Timestamp with aggregation framework in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, underscore.js, momentjs, aggregation-framework

I have the below array of object from my MongoDB query to get some statistics based on time:

```
[
    { 
        _id: { year: 2014, dayOfYear: 128, hour: 9 },
        count: 2,
        avg: 0.12455,
        min: 0.1245,
        max: 0.1246, 
        gv: 7.98954654895666, 
        bv: 0.9950000000000001 
    },
    { 
        _id: { year: 2014, dayOfYear: 134, hour: 14 },
        count: 8,
        avg: 0.12217854,
        min: 0.1212,
        max: 0.12345678,
        gv: 25.869999999999997,
        bv: 3.1652450614477337
    },
    { 
        _id: { year: 2014, dayOfYear:126, hour: 19 },
        count: 3,
        avg: 0.11234099999999998,
        min: 0.112341,
        max: 0.112341,
        gv: 29.849999999999998,
        bv: 3.3533788500000004
    }
]
```

I want to basically convert the _id object into a unix timestamp with moment.js I just cant to find the right underscore function to iterate through the objects, get the ID data and make an array out of it again.

In the process i could just do moment().year('2014').format('Z')

result wanted:

```
{
    unixtime: 1400599394,
    count: 3,
    avg: 0.11234099999999998,
    min: 0.112341,
    max: 0.112341,
    gv: 29.849999999999998,
    bv: 3.3533788500000004
}
```

Comment: Is this actually output from the aggregation framework? If so what is your real purpose? Do you just want to group per "hour" within each day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that you did ask for how to do this with promises, but I'm just taking a stab here based on the naming of the fields under `_id` that this is actually output from the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and therefore there is another way to do this.

The [date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) that you appear to have used are great for their purposes, but as you seem to want a unix timestamp as the output then the logical thing to do is keep that field in unix timestamp format, just with the grouping boundaries you need.

This seems to be grouping "per hour" within each day, so let's apply the date math in order to alter that timestamp value. So instead of using the date operators to break up the date in your [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline key, do this instead:

```js
{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "$subtract": [ 
            { "$subtract": [ "$created", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
            { "$mod": [ 
                { "$subtract": [ "$created", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                1000*60*60 
            ]}
        ]
    }
}}
```

Of course include all the other things you have in your aggregation pipeline ( which are not supplied in this question ), but the result is the actual epoch timestamp value being truncated to the hour of the day from your original date field which is named "created".

Just to break down the parts of this consider this date object:

```
var date = new Date()
date.valueOf()
1400639001169
```

So there you see the epoch timestamp representation extracted from the date object. In terms of the math, retrieving that value via the `.valueOf()` method is exactly the same as:

```
date - new Date("1970-01-01")
1400639001169
```

Which provides you with the seconds ( or milliseconds in this case ) elapsed since "1970-01-01", which is exactly what epoch time is. To further this we can get the milliseconds elapsed in 1 hour as a portion of this date by obtaining the modulus:

```
date % ( 1000*60*60 )
1401169
```

So with 1000 milliseconds in a second, 60 seconds in a minute and 60 minutes in an hour we obtain this result. All that is left now is to subtract that value from the original date value:

```
date - date % ( 1000*60*60 )
1400637600000
```

And that value is now the boundary of the hour in the day and suitable for grouping as well as being the desired result you want in your output. Just for reference, here are the string formatted values of the initial and converted timestamp:

```
    Initial:   Wed, 21 May 2014 02:23:21 GMT
    Converted: Wed, 21 May 2014 02:00:00 GMT
```

So basically you are doing the same thing for grouping that you are using the [date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) for, but actually getting the output format you want without requiring additional conversion.

Just a cool trick that if I'm right about how you got here should be useful to you and if not, then at least should be useful to others who might have arrived here in exactly that way.

Comment: You sir, are a genious!! Yes i grouped it already with aggregation this was pretty straight forward. i could not find a decent way to make the "hourdayyears etc." back to a timestamp.. ill checked the answer and it works perfect. seemes way better then using all javascript workarounds. Thank you Neil.

Comment: @xanatas No problem, like I said, it looked like that was what you were doing. Pitty your question is titled and worded towards the JavaScript solution. Mind if I do some editing there?